# SVN Merge Conflicts Markers Without Common Ancestor ("diff3")

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

when I try to do a merge between branches and I hit a conflict, I get the conflict markers in the "diff3" form. (I'm doing the merging using TortoiseSVN, but I think this shouldn't have any impact on the underlying SVN commands?)

```
<<<<<<< .working
    public static function createFooXyz()
||||||| .merge-left.r2
    public static function createFoo()
=======
    public static function createFooAbc()
>>>>>>> .merge-right.r5
```

However, I dislike this style, and would rather prefer to see the more compact form without common ancestor (that git uses when diff3 format is not used).

```
<<<<<<< .working
    public static function createFooXyz()
=======
    public static function createFooAbc()
>>>>>>> .merge-right.r5
```

Is it possible to force SVN 1.10 to use the second formating for merge conflicts?